# How to draw many polygons and polylines in sub thread in wp7

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, draw

I am developing a Windows Phone App which needs draw a lot of polygons and polylines in runtime.

I have searched the google and stackoverflow found that `Dispatcher.BeginInovoke()` can't satisfy my needs. Because I must create the `DependencyObject`s such as `Polygon` and `Polyline` in my non-UI thread. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think Dispatcher is not sutable for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create ui element in your non-ui thread .

you must use dispather to make your ui thread execute ui action or else it will throw exception.

for example :

```
            ThreadHelper.RunInNewThread(() =>
            {

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 

                         //something you want ui thread do
                    );

            }, 10);
```